# Automating SQL Server Merge Replication Processes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication, merge

Hi all is there anyway I can automate the entire process of the Merge Replication?

Comment: Which DBMS are we talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Automate what, exactly? The creation, the monitoring..? You need to be more specific, so please describe a scenario and some thoughts about it that you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some sps (stored procs) on SQL Server, that can be used to setup merge replication.

Enabling merge replication on a db: sp_replicationdboption  'db name', 'merge publish', true

Creating a merge publication: exec sp_addmergepublication

Adding snapshot agent job: [exec sp_addpublication_snapshot ....

Adding each article: exec sp_addmergearticle

Configuring added/removed columns: exec sp_mergearticlecolumn (if needed only, by default, all columns are part of publication)

However, I am not sure of Transactional and other types of replication. Please let me know, if this is not what you intended.